# SQL: Select group by and its last transaction date

Tags: sql

my table looks like this

```
   id | email         | To  | amount | date
--------------------------------------------------
    1 | ben@gmail.com | bob | 100    | 12/may/2022
    2 | ben@gmail.com | jon | 100    | 12/may/2022
    3 | bob@gmail.com | ben | 50     | 12/may/2022
    4 | ben@gmail.com | bob | 25     | 13/may/2022
    5 | bob@gmail.com | jon | 10     | 14/may 2022
```

i want to group by "to" and sum the amount of each group and also get the latest transaction date of a particular group

My current query is:

```
select to, sum(amount) as "amount"
from transactions
where email = 'ben@gmail.com'
group by to
```

this gives me

```
  to  | amount
-----------------
  bob | 125
  jon | 100
```

I want to get the latest transaction date also

```
to  | amount | date
bob | 125    | 13/may/2022
jon | 100    | 12/may/2022
```

Comment: Your query differs from the supplied table layout (where is `remitter`?)

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Column date data type?

Comment: column date is currently a varchar you can change it if you want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the datatype of column date is DATETIME then try below query

```
select to, sum(amount) as "amount", MAX(date) as date
from transactions
where email = 'ben@gmail.com'
group by to
```

Or convert date column to datetime and take MAX value in select query